# Two assignments on same line in GNU makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

A certain makefile (namely, the otherlibs/num/Makefile in the OCaml 4.2 distribution) has the following line :

```
EXTRACFLAGS=-DBNG_ARCH_$(BNG_ARCH) -DBNG_ASM_LEVEL=$(BNG_ASM_LEVEL)
```

I am surprised to see two assignments on the same line here. What does it mean ? Is it the same as

```
EXTRACFLAGS=-DBNG_ARCH_$(BNG_ARCH)
-DBNG_ASM_LEVEL=$(BNG_ASM_LEVEL)
```

I did not find anything about that in the GNU make manual, maybe I am unaware of the right keyword to search this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are not two assignments here. The line assigns the definition:

```
-DBNG_ARCH_$(BNG_ARCH) -DBNG_ASM_LEVEL=$(BNG_ASM_LEVEL)
```

to the make variable `EXTRACFLAGS`. The value appears to consist
of flags that are to be passed to some invocation of the C preprocessor to
define macros `BNG_ARCH_$(BNG_ARCH)` and `BNG_ASM_LEVEL`. E.g. as
in a make recipe:

```
    $(CPP) $(EXTRACFLAGS) ...
```

Which, supposing the make assignments:

```
BNG_ARCH = foo
BNG_ASM_LEVEL = bar
```

would expand to:

```
    cpp -DBNG_ARCH_foo -DBNG_ASM_LEVEL=bar ...
```

**OP comments**:

> So you might say that = is "left-associative", the leftmost = sign is the one that really gets executed. Is this documented somewhere in the manual?

From my frequent, but far from exhaustive resorts to manual I can't say it *is* documented. Somebody
may know better. There is no formal grammar there, but it is everywhere illustrated that the definition of a variable extends from the
start of the non-whitespace text following `=`, `:=` or `?=` to the end of the (possibly `\`-extended)
logical line. You may satisfied on the point by running the makefile:

```
.PHONY: all

x = X y = Y

all:
    @echo [$(x)]
    @echo [$(y)]
```

which prints:

```
[X y = Y]
[]
```

Assignment signs within a make-definition are not assignments, they're just characters in the definition.

Comment: Thanks. So you might say that = is "left-associative", the leftmost = sign is the one that really gets executed. Is this documented somewhere in the manual ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Replied in answer

Comment: Thanks for this exhaustive answer